# Java PropertyChangeSupport using annotation

Tags: java, rcp, pojo, eclipse-databinding

Generally we use something like

```
public class Person {
    private final PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport =
        new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    ....
}
```

to make POJOs bindable to UI or able to listen property changes from other objects. Is there a framework/library we can use to make it annotation based? I am planning to use with RCP/JFace and the solution using Java Agent in [JFace Data Binding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/PojoBindable#Pojo_Bindable_in_Action) seems a bit heavy weight. [This](http://yakafokon.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/beans-binding-jsr-295-with-pojo-and-aop/) AspectJ based solution also looks a bit overkill. Just wondering if there are other lighter solutions available out there.